# Pathfinding using mesh distance field in UE4

Tags: unreal-engine4

I want to access Unreal Mesh Distance Field in or order to do some A* or alternative path finding.
My environment needs wall and ceiling walkers as well as flying bots. The out of the box Navmesh is 2D and won't work for me.
Has anyone tried this?

Comment: That sounds not performant and like it would be tough. The recast mesh has nav links that might suffice for wall and ceiling walkers. For flyers I would try simple avoidance, there's plenty knocking around the internet about that. If it's not good enough then my suggestion would be to implement a new `ANavData` and have that generate a 3d grid masked out by collision.

Comment: Thanks! My thought was that MeshDistance Fields were created anyway, and you could clamp the "depth" so you didn't waste time finding paths that are pointless. And I wanted to created intelligences on walls and ceiling as thats where my character plays too. Imagine giant space colony with spinning to create gravity.